# How to compare two dates with datatype VARCHAR2?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to create a new column in my DB that represent the STATUS of my FLOWS.

In my case, I want to use a CASE-WHEN condition.

For example:

if I have this column that represent END_DATE:

```
`20-SETT-23 12:59`, `21-SETT-23:16:15`, `22-OTT-23 23:49`,
```

I want that `CASE STATUS = KO if END_DATE > 23:45` , else STATUS = OK.

How can I do to make this condition with this END_DATE?

I expect that STATUS in my table must be OK or KO

Comment: Don't store date/time in varchar columns. Use a proper date/time data type instead, and comparisons will become much easier.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: To add to @jarlh: Not only comparisons but also sorting and error handling are way easier with the correct datatype.. Keep in mind you can always 'CAST' to another datatype. Even in SQL.

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/cast.php

Comment: If you cannot cast the string in your locale to a regular date you have to parse and confirm it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

select
case when extract(hour from dt)>= 23 and extract(minute from dt) >= 45 then 'KO' else 'OK' end as status
from
(select cast(to_date('20-SEP-23 12:59','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi') as timestamp) as dt from dual union all
select cast(to_date('21-SEP-23 16:15','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi') as timestamp) from dual union all
select cast(to_date('22-OCT-23 23:49','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi') as timestamp) from dual)

Answer (score 0):

You've already been told that storing dates as strings isn't the best idea. Sample data you posted - if that illustrates what you really have - shows exactly that: "date format" isn't always the same (sometimes you have colon between date and hour, sometimes not) so converting the whole string to a valid date won't always succeed. However - as sample data suggests - the last 5 characters seem to be hours:minutes and that's what you're interested in - date is irrelevant.

This is just for displaying purposes - you don't have to do that:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi';

Session altered.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (end_date) as
  2    (select '20-SETT-23 12:59' from dual union all
  3     select '21-SETT-23:16:15' from dual union all
  4     select '22-OTT-23 23:49'  from dual
  5    )
```

- `hhmi` shows date value based on the last 5 characters in `hh24:mi` format
- `comp_hhmi` shows value `hhmi` is to be compared to
- `status` is what you're looking for

Query:

```
  6  select end_date,
  7    to_date(substr(end_date, -5), 'hh24:mi') hhmi,
  8    to_date('23:45', 'hh24:mi') comp_hhmi,
  9    --
 10    case when to_date(substr(end_date, -5), 'hh24:mi') > to_date('23:45', 'hh24:mi') then 'KO'
 11         else 'OK'
 12    end status
 13  from test;

END_DATE         HHMI             COMP_HHMI        STATUS
---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ------
20-SETT-23 12:59 01.12.2023 12:59 01.12.2023 23:45 OK
21-SETT-23:16:15 01.12.2023 16:15 01.12.2023 23:45 OK
22-OTT-23 23:49  01.12.2023 23:49 01.12.2023 23:45 KO

SQL>
```

If there's another kind of garbage in that column, e.g. `82-SETT-F8 54:97` (because nothing prevents you from storing it into a `varchar2` column), that query - of course - won't work.

Comment: mmm It doesn't work. There is another way to compare this END_DATE? I know that it is wrong in  VARCHAR2 format but i cannot change it. Please

Comment: It *works* with sample data you provided (and I used). Re-read my last sentence about *another kind of garbage*. You'll first have to clean it up if you want to use a single query. Otherwise, you might need to write a PL/SQL procedure which would go row-by-row and compare various versions of *garbage* you have, trying to recognize what it contains, convert it to something "valid" (apparently, HH24:MI format) and return desired result.

Comment: ok it works, but now I am having some issues about some comparison. For example, with this condition : For example, I have some END_DATE like 00:20, 00:45, 01:00 which are referring of the next day and I want that 23:45 > 00:20. For example, if I Have END DATE like 22-SETT-23 23:58, 23-SETT-23 00:25, I want that the 23-SETT-23 00:25 define status KO because later than 23:45

Comment: That's not what the original question says. You never mentioned any DATE component. If you want to do that, you'll have to "transform" all END_DATE values so that they contain both DATE and TIME (using TO_DATE function with appropriate format mask) and then compare such a DATE value (not a string!) to another DATE value that contains date and time component. Because, just with TIME, your question doesn't make much sense. *Anything* can be after 23:45 (including 00:25, 08:18 and 23:38 - all belonging to dates that follow the one you're comparing them with).

Comment: ok. Thank you. Another question: now I have 2 VARCHAR2: DT_CHECKPOINT and END_TIME. DT_CHECKPOINT is like: 05/11/2023 and DT_FLOW_END is like: 05/10/2023 21:16. Now how can I do to compare DT_CHECKPOINT and DT_FLOW_END? For example in this case i want to do that 05/11/23 > 05/10/2023

Comment: Compare TO_DATE(DT_CHECKPOINT, 'dd/mm/yyyy') with TO_DATE(SUBSTR(END_DATE, 1, 10), 'dd/mm/yyyy')

Answer (score 0):

It is not good to have dates stored as strings and it is even worse if those strings are bad (like SETT instead of SET).  Anyway, there are always a few options to get out of it. Let's first create some context...

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'Italian';
--Session modificato.
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'Italy';
--Session modificato.
```

... create some sample data to work with:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl AS
        ( Select 1 "ID", '20-SETT-23 12:59' "STR_DT" From Dual Union All
          Select 2 "ID", '21-SETT-23:16:15' "STR_DT" From Dual Union All
          Select 3 "ID", '22-OTT-23 23:49' "STR_DT" From Dual 
        ),
```

Now, to work with dates we should transform your strings into DATE data types. Oracle DATE datatype holds 7 informations - century, year, month, day, hour, minute, and second. There are different formats used for each of them - in your data there is a mistaken representation for month (SETT instead of SET) - this kind of month represantation has structured key 'MON' used in date conversion functions. Next query (cte) will convert your strings into Oracle dates replacing the mistaken month with correct one...

```sql
    tbl2 AS
        ( Select  ID, STR_DT, To_Date(Replace(STR_DT, '-SETT-', '-SET-'), 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi') "DT"
          From    tbl
        )
--  T e s t :
Select * From tbl2
/*
        ID STR_DT            DT       
---------- ----------------  ---------
         1 20-SETT-23 12:59  20-SET-23
         2 21-SETT-23:16:15  21-SET-23
         3 22-OTT-23 23:49   22-OTT-23  */
```

... finaly, having a DATE data type column DT, there are numerous options to test the date (time) for last 15 minutes. Here are 2 of them. STAT_1 extracts string 'hh24mi' and process it with case expression. STAT_2 uses date calculation substracting your DT from tommorrow trunncated to 00:00:00 which gives us result in days. When we multiply the result with 24 (hours per day) and with 60 (minutes per hour) - the result is in minutes - case expression does the rest...

```sql
Select  ID, STR_DT,
        Case When To_Char(DT, 'hh24mi') > '2345' Then 'KO' Else 'OK' End "STAT_1",
        Case When (TRUNC(DT + 1) - DT)  * 24 * 60 < 15 Then 'KO' Else 'OK' End "STAT_2"
From    tbl2
/*
        ID STR_DT           STAT_1 STAT_2
---------- ---------------- ------ ------
         1 20-SETT-23 12:59 OK     OK
         2 21-SETT-23:16:15 OK     OK
         3 22-OTT-23 23:49  KO     KO     */
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are storing date/times in an inappropriate data type (string). This leads to having to deal with various formats (and maybe even invalid entries).

You are interested in the time part, which is at the end of the string. Unfortunately, there can or can not be seconds in the string, and if there are seconds then we need them, because you want to check whether the time is greater than 23:45 - and 23:45 is not, and 23:45:00 is not, but 23:45:01 to 23:45:59 are.

We can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to get the time and then `RPAD` to add the seconds in case they are missing:

```
SELECT 
  dt, 
  RPAD(REGEXP_SUBSTR(dt, '(\d\d:?)*$'), 8, ':00') AS time,
  CASE WHEN RPAD(REGEXP_SUBSTR(dt, '(\d\d:?)*$'), 8, ':00') > '23:45:00' THEN 'KO' ELSE 'OK' END AS status
FROM mytable;
```

This query doesn't check whether the stored date/time is valid. If it is invalid, the status may become OK or KO depending on the content.