# I would to put allo values on 'KO' in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am in a situation like this: I have 4 job_names that go into KO or OK status depending on whether they pass a certain time. I am handling the situation with CASE-WHEN and what I need to do is the following: if even ONLY one of these jobs has a time greater than 23:45, then ALL JOBs will have KO status.
For example:
if I have record 1: `job1   (24/10/2023 23:45)  (25/10/2023 00:54)  (25/10/2023 01:14)  (Ended OK)  (KO)` and `job2   (24/10/2023 21:45)    (25/10/2023 22:56)  (25/10/2023 23:17)  (Ended OK)  (OK)`

I would to put both job on KO.

my code is this:

```
WHEN a.JOB_NAME IN ('job1','job2','job3','job4') AND
(
    (a.JOB_NAME = 'job1' AND 
    (
        (TO_DATE(a.ORDER_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_DATE(SUBSTR(a.END_TIME, 1, 10), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
        to_date(substr(a.END_TIME, -5), 'hh24:mi') > to_date('23:45', 'hh24:mi'))
        OR 
        (TO_DATE(a.ORDER_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') < TO_DATE(SUBSTR(a.END_TIME, 1, 10), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
        to_date(substr(a.END_TIME, -5), 'hh24:mi') > to_date('00:00', 'hh24:mi'))
    ))
    OR
    (a.JOB_NAME = 'job2' AND 
    (
        (TO_DATE(a.ORDER_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_DATE(SUBSTR(a.END_TIME, 1, 10), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
        to_date(substr(a.END_TIME, -5), 'hh24:mi') > to_date('23:45', 'hh24:mi'))
        OR 
        (TO_DATE(a.ORDER_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') < TO_DATE(SUBSTR(a.END_TIME, 1, 10), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
        to_date(substr(a.END_TIME, -5), 'hh24:mi') > to_date('00:00', 'hh24:mi'))
    ))
    OR
    (a.JOB_NAME = 'job3' AND 
    (
        (TO_DATE(a.ORDER_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_DATE(SUBSTR(a.END_TIME, 1, 10), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
        to_date(substr(a.END_TIME, -5), 'hh24:mi') > to_date('23:45', 'hh24:mi'))
        OR 
        (TO_DATE(a.ORDER_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') < TO_DATE(SUBSTR(a.END_TIME, 1, 10), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
        to_date(substr(a.END_TIME, -5), 'hh24:mi') > to_date('00:00', 'hh24:mi'))
    ))
    OR
    (a.JOB_NAME = 'job4' AND 
    (
        (TO_DATE(a.ORDER_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_DATE(SUBSTR(a.END_TIME, 1, 10), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
        to_date(substr(a.END_TIME, -5), 'hh24:mi') > to_date('23:45', 'hh24:mi'))
        OR 
        (TO_DATE(a.ORDER_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') < TO_DATE(SUBSTR(a.END_TIME, 1, 10), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
        to_date(substr(a.END_TIME, -5), 'hh24:mi') > to_date('00:00', 'hh24:mi'))
    ))
) AND a.COMPLETION_STATUS = 'Ended OK' THEN 'KO'
```

Comment: Business requirement aside, what technical issue are you facing? Also, are the dates really strings stored in 'DD/MM/YYYY' format? `to_date('23:45', 'hh24:mi')` is 23:45 on 1st of the current month, not today. Is that expected? Sample data in tabular format would help a lot.

Comment: You asked practicaly the same question @MarioS at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77679853/how-to-compare-two-dates-with-datatype-varchar2/77681376#77681376 and received 4 answers. Maybe you could check them out. And, BTW, there are no times in your data that are greater than 23:45 and the closest one is 23:45 which is equal, not greater than 23:45.

Answer (score 0):

Means you are storing the dates in the string data type column?

You can check the condition for all the jobs in one go and also You can convert the date and directly check if it is greater then `ORDER_DATE`'s 23:45 as follows:

```
CASE 
WHEN a.JOB_NAME IN ('job1','job2','job3','job4') 
 AND TO_DATE(a.END_TIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') 
     > TO_DATE(a.ORDER_DATE || ' 23:45', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') 
 AND a.COMPLETION_STATUS = 'Ended OK' 
THEN 'KO'
```

**Note:** It is recommended not to store dates in `varchar` data type column.